# Security flaws of keeping sensitive information inside javascript code

Tags: javascript, security, local-storage, bundler

Everybody knows that you shouldn't keep `sensitiveInfo` variable at your js code. The better way is to put it inside local storage. Could you pls explain vulnerabilities of the first approach with help of my example?

**Example:**
You use bundler, which bundle all your js files together. `sensitiveInfo` isn't global, but stored inside `YourStorage.js`. To access file which keeps it you do:

```
import YourStorage from 'somepath/YourStorage';
YourStorage.sensitiveInfo = newValue; // QUESTION: can you steal this value? Is it accessible from console?
```

**Questions:**

1. Is `sensitiveInfo` variable accessible from console?
2. Could you please describe mechanism how someone can steal `sensitiveInfo`?
3. If someone can steal it from my code, why he couldn't from local storage?

---

*UPDATE: (whom I'm trying to protect from?)* I'm writing mobile web app, where users can spend real money. I want to protect them from all kinds of attack where they can loose their money (i.e. locally installed viruses)

Comment: *Whom* are you trying to protect *from*?

Comment: You can get anything back out of local storage.  It's just plain text and very easily accessible.  You probably shouldn't store sensitive data in local storage at all.

Comment: @JosephMarikle where to store authToken for autologin then?

Comment: @deceze trying to protect from all bad people) Sorry, do you mean some specific kinds of atacks?

Comment: Tokens are different.  Tokens are the browser side of a remote session.  The token itself is an otherwise meaningless hash, so it's safe to store that locally.  The sensitive information would then be stored in the session on the remote server.

Comment: @JosephMarikle but if you steal token, you can log in as user and fetch all sensitive info, right?

Comment: "All bad people" is too broad. Does that include "bad people" sitting at the user's keyboard? Or locally installed viruses? You should narrow down your attack scenario to decide what you *must* worry about and what is out of your hands either way.

Comment: @deceze I'm writing mobile web app, where users can spend real money. I want to protect them from all kinds of attack where they can loose their money (localy installed viruses, my users may open bad sites in next browser tab). No, bad people doesn't sitting at user's keyboard, have no idea how to protect in that case

Comment: @deceze Could you please suppose other attack scenarios?

Comment: virus attacks are essentially the same as "someone sitting at the keyboard" because it will probably look no different than actual user activity to your application.  There's little you can do about that except maybe put in checks for unusual activity (large number of transactions in a short timespan for instance).  As far as getting the token to the user, just make sure you transmit it in an encrypted format (e.g. use an SSL to server your web app).  Beyond that, there's not a whole lot you can do more to ensure no one steals the token.

Comment: @JosephMarikle so the all thing is to keep secure connection? Why then all avoid keeping sensitive data at js code?

Comment: Because it's another layer of security.  You grant access to the information (through your app) without directly giving the information.  I'll use website forms as an example: You don't want to give people your email address, but you want people to email you; so instead, you give people access to email you by allowing them to send a message through a form on a website.  You can help keep your information (your email) secure by limit access to it through your application.

Comment: You are also free to add further security for that access.  Someone may get a user's session token, but even with that you can require them to answer security questions before access more secure data.  All this is not possible if you just store the sensitive data locally.  Lastly, while I feel I have some grasp of online security, [these guys](http://security.stackexchange.com/) will know way more than I do.  You should check out that exchange site, search for answers, or ask questions to learn more on the intricacies of session security over the web.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I'm generation token in Java. But anycase I need keep it on client and it may be stolen. Sorry, I didn't get your example below. Could you provide another one please? I would very appreciate it

Comment: Yeah... It was a pretty bad example.  Maybe if you think about as actual keys for an office building.  You don't just give someone their work computer to take home with them.  You give them keys to the building.  You can control the environment better that way.  You know that the doors stay locked and that cameras are always recording.  You can trust yourself with the office equipment, but you don't know how secure each person's house is.  It might be secure, but you don't know, so instead of giving them the equipment directly, you only give them access to the equipment by keys.

Comment: @JosephMarikle you mean keeping sensitive data inside js code is like allow someone keep work computer to home, right? And what is giving them a key from building?

Comment: The session token is the key.  Someone evil can steal the key, but even then, your application can stand guard and ask anyone with a key for their password or security questions before getting to the really important equipment.   They key/token doesn't need to allow them immediate access to the sensitive data. It can just let them in the building (or for your application, allow them to make purchases), but even if that happens, it's not as bad as them getting direct access to credit cards or birth date or bank info.  Purchases can be refunded, but lost sensitive info is a lot harder to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Anything put in javaScript that is downloadable can be easily seen on the users device.  The most common method of securing sensitive information that must be passed back and forth to a client is to:

First, use SSL to encrypt the information over the 'wire'.

Second, if the data is of a very sensitive nature - such as a token used to process credit card information (do not store the card number in this token!) - that data should be encrypted itself, using a seed/key that is securely stored on the application server.

Often you would write the application to require both the identify of the user AND the device be verified.  After this verification, you would then decrypt the token - using a key stored only on, and only available from, the server-side of your application.

Using this practice you can reasonably assume the user and device are whom they say there are.  Of course, such applications need proper authentication themselves - with said credentials not being stored on the device - to prevent stolen devices from easily being used to access the application account/data.  Do not simply rely on a devices screen lock for security.

Comment: Much better and much more concise explanation than my feeble attempts in the comments.  Out of my own curiosity, how do you ensure user **and device** identity?  Most device information is pretty easy to spoof (MAC address, IP).  You have to trust that the information it's sending you is accurate anyway, right? So then is there really a point to asking the device for its identity?

Comment: There are various methods depending on what the device is.  Often items like smart phones and tablets each have unique keys (like serial numbers) that can be used during account set-up to say that 'this user is on this device'.  IPs and MAC are seldom used anymore, the IP can easily be changed when the user connects to a different network, and MAC numbers are easily spoofed.  If such a unique key isn't available, one is usually provided when the user sets up the account and stored (in encrypted form) on the device.

Comment: @Blackthorne thanks for your answer! Could you please explain how to autologin with token should work in your scheme? You said that I should firstly identify user and only then decrypt the token. But how I can identify user without token?

Comment: An automatic login generally requires the user to login a single time.  After this single successful login a unique, often single use, certificate is issued to the users devices.  This certificate is then presented for authentication in future logins, and often replaced when single-use forms are used.  This is a form of single-sign-on, or federated authentication.

Comment: The token (or certificate) is something passed back and forth between the server and the client - often using cookies for web-based apps.  The seed/key set used to encrypt/decrypt the token is stored only on the server.  Basically the token is of little use to someone without the seed/key.  Of course, the seed/key will have to be stored securely.  I find it best to randomly generate, as needed, a part or all of these seeds/keys and securely store them (in encrypted form) provides the best security.  It eliminates many issues with guessed keys.